# Between SynPackManager, Update Manager, and apt-get, which is the healthiest for my system?

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, update-manager, synaptic

I've been bouncing a lot between a few different update methods to see which I prefer the most, and I was wondering which of these is the 'healthiest' for the system, or what your preferred update method is.

Answer (score 3):

They all use `apt` in the end. Use whichever front end you prefer.